# Product grid display issue

Tags: product, grid, catalog

I am new on magento and after instal magento 1.9.3 I facing with following problems:

- First Issue: If I set catalog as grid view the cart text and price are over the short description;
- Second Issue: in the list view mode the product picture not displaying correct ratio. My theme is rwd (default 1.9.3) enclosed pictures or my web address **www.agroimpex.ro**

[image: grid_view]

Comment: Hello @BogdanZaval, welcome! Do you have the same problem when your CSS is not merged?

Comment: yes, same, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div that got the `action` class is set to `position:absolute;`

Try removing that one and re-check:
[image]

Comment: @BogdanZaval you're welcome. You may just accept the answer if it fixed your problem ;)